# setInterval in AJAX without using a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to setInterval for my AJAX code:

```
    var color;
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "test.php",    
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
            success: function(data){
            color = data;
            console.log(color);
        }
    });
```

but if I use a function my variable color doesn't get recognized by JavaScript.

```
    setInterval (function(){
    var color;
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "test.php",    
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
            success: function(data){
            color = data;
            console.log(color);
        }
    });
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define color outside of the function

```
    var color;

    setInterval (function(){

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "test.php",    
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
            success: function(data){
            color = data;
            console.log(color);
        }
    });
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adrian. I have used your solution but if I console.log color outside of this function it is undefined.

Comment: Read up on variable scope.

Comment: by the way `async : false` is evil